# C: Difference between U64 and uint64_t

Tags: c, types, long-integer

I am trying to learn C after working with Java for a couple of years.
I've found some code that I wanted to reproduce which looked something like this:

```
U64 attack_table[...]; // ~840 KiB 

struct SMagic {
   U64* ptr;  // pointer to attack_table for each particular square
   U64 mask;  // to mask relevant squares of both lines (no outer squares)
   U64 magic; // magic 64-bit factor
   int shift; // shift right
};

SMagic mBishopTbl[64];
SMagic mRookTbl[64];

U64 bishopAttacks(U64 occ, enumSquare sq) {
   U64* aptr = mBishopTbl[sq].ptr;
   occ      &= mBishopTbl[sq].mask;
   occ      *= mBishopTbl[sq].magic;
   occ     >>= mBishopTbl[sq].shift;
   return aptr[occ]; 
}

U64 rookAttacks(U64 occ, enumSquare sq) {
   U64* aptr = mRookTbl[sq].ptr;
   occ      &= mRookTbl[sq].mask;
   occ      *= mRookTbl[sq].magic;
   occ     >>= mRookTbl[sq].shift;
   return aptr[occ];
}
```

The code is not that important but I already failed at using the same datatype: `U64`, I only found `uint64_t`. Now I would like to know where the difference in `U64`, `uint64_t` and `long` is.

I am very happy if someone could briefly explain this one to me, including the advantage of each of them.

Greetings,
Finn

Comment: `U64` is shorter than `uint64_t`.  `U64` is not standardized; `uint64_t` is standardized by C99 and C11.

Comment: And how and why would one use U64 then?

Comment: You'd use `U64` only when you know the platform on which you're compiling defines it, and how it defines it, and that it defines it the way you think it is going to be defined, and so on.  Personally, I'd probably not use `U64` ever, but YMMV.

Comment: The idea is to use magic bitboards in which I will use stuff like bitwise-xor etc. To do this as efficient as possible, i would need a datatype with exactly 64 bits so that the cpu could do it with one cycle.

Comment: If it is defined (it might not be, in theory; in practice, on most machines outside the embedded space, it is defined), then `uint64_t` is an unsigned integer type with exactly 64 bits.  (If `uint64_t` isn't defined, `U64` probably isn't going to be defined either, or it isn't going to be defined the way you want/expect it to be defined.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR - for a 64-bit exact width unsigned integer, `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint64_t`.

---

Presumably, `U64` is a custom typedef for 64-bit wide unsigned integer.

If you're using at least a C99 compliant compiler, it would have `<stdint.h>` with a `typedef` for *64-bit wide unsigned integer with no padding bits*: `uint64_t`. However, it might be that the code targets a compiler that doesn't have the standard `uint64_t` defined. In that case, there might be some configuration header where a type is chosen for `U64`. Perhaps you can `grep` the files for `typedef.*U64;`

---

`long` on the other hand, is a **signed type**. Due to various undefined and implementation-defined aspects of signed math, you wouldn't want to use a signed type for bit-twiddling **at** all. Another complication is that unlike in Java, the C `long` doesn't have a standardized width; instead `long` is allowed to be only 32 bits wide - and it is so on most 32-bit platforms, and even on 64-bit Windows. If you ever need exact width types, you wouldn't use `int` or `long`. Only `long long` and `unsigned long long` are guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide.